# Marking up colored text in Org

Tags: org-mode, colors, spreadsheet

I want to generate an Excel spreadsheet programmatically from an Org document. Any tips on how to markup colored text? I understand that Org does not natively support color markup, wondering if there's something else I can use just so I can translate it later to Excel formatting.

Comment: Why do you need colored text for that? If you have a table, you can write it out as CSV (see `orgtbl-to-csv`) which Excel can import.

Comment: I know I can export to CSV, or even just view the Org document as-is, but the table is to be presented to a layman and colors are used as visual helpers.